# Centos Crontab not responding

Tags: centos, cron

I was learning and experimenting with **crontab** today.

The default editor was just too difficult for me to figure out which caused me to remove my crontab by running **crontab -r**.

Now, when I run **crontab -e** and input my new cron task, nothing happens.
I suspect it's the ***crontab -r*** command I executed earlier.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Next time please provide the cron job you try to run so that we can understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did crontab -e, nothing happens and it returned you normal prompt ?

if it gives you an empty space you should enter your variables like :

```
0 0 * * * /opt//newauditlog.ksh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

After you did that you can exit with :wq!

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a RTFM question to me ;-)

`man crontab`

> The -e option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor
>   specified by the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables.
>   After you exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed automatically. If neither of the environment variables is defined,
>   then the default editor /usr/bin/editor is used.

So the -e option should "automatically install the modified crontab"

Make sure there is a file matching your username and your jobs in */var/spool/cron/crontabs* and check the content of */etc/cron.allow* and */etc/cron.deny*

Also, look that the cron daemon is running:
`ps aux | grep cron`

Comment: non of those files (cron.allow nor cron.deny) nor any matching username file exits in /var/spool/cron/crontabs

Comment: Then this means the "crontab" utility is not doing its job. See my update